# 'int' object is not callable exception

Tags: python

Can't find what's wrong with this code. Can someone help me to fix this, please ?

```
def f(x):
    a = (-5 * (int(x) ** 5) + 69 (int(x) ** 2) - 47)
    return a

print f(0)
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An operator is needed between `69` and  `(int(x) ** 2)`.
If you meant to use multiplication, then you need to use `*` explicitly

Comment: Adding to this correct answer, I'd suggest you break long expressions into smaller chunks and use temporary variables.. It makes the code a bit longer but much more readable, also easier to avoid these kinds of silly syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

in this sequence

```
a = (-5 * (int(x) ** 5) + 69 (int(x) ** 2) - 47)
```

`69` is considered as function call because of the open parenthesis `(`, so python tries to call `69` as callable but `int` instance is not callable.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an operation between the `69` and  `(int(x) ** 2)` in your equation.